# I want to create firebase security rules for my flutter app. I am using cloud firestore and I am using google sign in without firebase auth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I use firebase.auth like this,

`allow read,write : if request.auth != null;`

It says not enough permissions in debug console...because I am not using firebase auth and want to know that is there any workaround for google sign in without firebase auth. I am new to firebase. Thanks

Comment: How do you intend to use Google Sign-in - this is configured as a Auth Service provider in Firebase Auth. So, in your app, if the user signs in using Google Auth, then Firebase Auth actually captures the authentication and your firestore rule of `request.auth != null` should work. Check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin or video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHFV6JPp-6A

Comment: I am signing in a user using their google sign in account

Comment: handleSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount account) async {
    if (account != null) {
      await createUserInFirestore();
      setState(() {
        isAuth = true;
      });
      configurePushNotifications();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isAuth = false;
      });
    }
  }

Comment: and then creating their account in firestore

Comment: createUserInFirestore() async {
    // 1) check if user exists in users collection in database (according to their id)
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.document(user.id).get();

    if (!doc.exists) {
      // 2) if the user doesn't exist, then we want to take them to the create account page
      final username = await Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));

Comment: I feel, you should use Firebase Authentication and leverage the Google Auth in Sign-in method.

Comment: Yes i think too thanks.

Comment: @Kuldeeprawat could you edit those parts of your code into the question and format them? they are quite difficult to read in the comments and in the way you shared them. Also, did the soltuion provided by Neelavar answered your question?